# Determining pressure of sublimation of iodine

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, phase, entropy

> The pressure of sublimation of iodine can theoretically be determined by considering the two hypothetical steps: the sublimation of iodine at $\pu{298 K}$, followed by an isothermal expansion of our system until it reaches the sublimation
>   pressure.
>
> a) Determine the enthalpy and entropy change for this process.
>   b) Determine the pressure of sublimation.
>
> **Given Data**
>
> - Triple point: $\mathrm{12.07~kPa, 113.0~^\circ C}$
> - Melting point: $\mathrm{113.7~^\circ C}$
> - Boiling point: $\mathrm{184.3~^\circ C}$
> - $C_{\mathrm m,p}{\left(\ce{I2 (s)}\right)} = 55.44 \mathrm{~J~K^{–1}~mol^{–1}}$
> - $C_{\mathrm m,p}{\left(\ce{I2 (l)}\right)} = 89.38 \mathrm{~J~K^{–1}~mol^{–1}}$
> - $C_{\mathrm m,p}{\left(\ce{I2 (g)}\right)} = 36.90 \mathrm{~J~K^{–1}~mol^{–1}}$
> - $\Delta_\text{f}H^\circ_\mathrm m{\left(\ce{I2(g)}\right)} = 62.44 \mathrm{~kJ~mol^{-1}}$
> - $S^\circ_\mathrm m{\left(\ce{I2(g)}\right)} = 260.6 \mathrm{~J~K^{-1}~mol^{-1}}$
> - $S^\circ_\mathrm m{\left(\ce{I2(s)}\right)} = 116.1 \mathrm{~J~K^{-1}~mol^{-1}}$

**My Attempt**

I have calculated the enthalpy and entropy change for the first step by using Hess's Law. They are $\mathrm{62.44~kJ~mol^{-1}}$ and $\mathrm{144.5~J~K^{-1}~mol^{-1}}$ respectively.

Now for the second step which is the isothermal expansion:

$$\Delta H = -nC_{\mathrm m,p}\Delta T = 0$$

For entropy:

$$\Delta S = nR\ln\left(\frac{V_\mathrm f}{V_\mathrm i}\right)$$

If assume that I have 1 mole of iodine I know what $n$ and $V_\mathrm i$ is but how am I suppose to know what $V_\mathrm f$ is?

Also I am struggling to understand the question. It says *isothermal expansion of our system until it reaches the sublimation pressure*. How are you suppose to know when it reaches sublimation pressure if it has already sublimed?

Comment: You know that the change in G in going from the solid to the vapor at the equilibrium sublimation pressure is zero, correct?  You also know that the free energy of formation of the solid at 298 K and 1 atm is zero, correct?  So, all you need to do is determine the free energy of formation of the vapor at the hypothetical state of 298 K and 1 atm, and then determine the pressure change necessary to bring that down to zero.